# Combining workbook values into a single column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task where I have two workbooks, one source and one destination.  The task is to search a column in the destination workbook for a value that contains a certain string.  When found, I have to search the source workbook in a certain column to find a matching string.  I then take values from 2 other columns in that same row in the source workbook, combine them, and write them to a cell in the destination workbook.

The issue is that the values are being written to the wrong rows in the destination workbook, like this:
[example1Broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuJAf.png)

When it should look like this:
[example2proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbgT5.png)

Here is my current vba:

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim col As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="CopyFromWorkbookSource.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=3)
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="CopyFromWorkbookDest.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3)
    Dim address As Variant
    Dim newAddressRow As Variant
    Dim sourceVal1 As Variant
    Dim sourceVal2 As Variant
'Dest wb number column that contains the search query
    Dim sourceCol As Integer
    sourceCol = 1
    wbDest.Activate
'col = Split(ActiveCell(1).address(1, 0), "$")(0)
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        var = Cells(i, sourceCol).Value
        If var Like "*WI*" And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, sourceCol).Value) Then
            wbSource.Activate
            Set Cell = Nothing
            Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=var, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Cell Is Nothing Then
' MsgBox "Nothing"
            Else
'We found a match!
                MsgBox "Found hit for " & var & ": " & Cell.address
'This is where the value was found in the source workbook
                address = Cell.address
'This is where the new value must go in the dest workbook NOTE the column letter must change!
                newAddressRow = Split(address, "$A$")(1)
'Get the cell values from the source wb
                sourceVal1 = Cells(newAddressRow, 2)
                sourceVal2 = Cells(newAddressRow, 3)
                MsgBox "SourceVal1: " & sourceVal1 & " SourceVal2: " & sourceVal2 & " Newaddressrow: " & newAddressRow & " i: " & i
'Activate the dest workbook for pasting
                wbDest.Activate
'Write the source wb values into a single cell in the dest wb
                Cells(i, 2).Value = sourceVal1 & Chr(10) & sourceVal2
            End If
        End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider removing the address variable and set the sourceVals using the found Cell's Row parameter. Also consider direct referencing workbooks and sheets instead of activating; see below.

```
  Sub CombineWorkbooks()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim sourceCol As Integer 'Destwb number column that contains the search query

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="CopyFromWorkbookSource.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=3)
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="CopyFromWorkbookDest.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3)
    sourceCol = 1
  
    ' start at 2 to dodge the header
    For i = 2 To wbDest.Sheets(1).Rows.Count
      'this conditional can be removed if all non-header rows will contain WI
        If wbDest.Sheets(1).Cells(i, sourceCol).Value Like "*WI*" Then

          Set Cell = wbSource.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Find(What:=wbDest.Sheets(1).Cells(i, sourceCol).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

          If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
           'We found a match!
           'Write the source wb values into a single cell in the dest wb
           Cells(i, 2).Value = wbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, 2) & Chr(10) & wbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, 3)
         End If
      End If
    Next i
  End Sub
```

[image: Results]

Comment: THANK YOU, this does exactly what I need it to.  I have written powershell for years but VBA and Excel are new to me, and this example you provided taught me a couple valuable lessons.

Comment: No problem. If you end up needing to reference the sheets by name, you can use the format wb.worksheet("name in quotes").Range() or .Cells()... This code assumes the sheets of interest are the first worksheet in both workbooks.